# Load UIPickerView with JSON Data (w/nested array)

Tags: ios, arrays, json, uipickerview, multidimensional-array

The JSON Data reads like this, where each object in the sites array has it's own array called "categories" as so :

```
"sites": [

{
  "nid": "25109",
  "name": "guard.com",
  "url": "http:\/\/www.trial.com\/guard\/",
  "description": null,

  "categories": [
    "Sports",
    "Security",
    "Product"
  ]

},

{
  "nid": "29402",
  "name": "paint.com",
  "url": "http:\/\/www.trial.com\/paint\/",
  "description": null,
  "categories": [
    "Sales",
    "Fashion",
    "Design"
  ]
```

},

I've added a UIPickerView to serve as a filter for my app.
I need to load a UIPickerView with all the categories from the JSON data. How do I parse the data ONLY from the categories array(s)?

Comment: Can you add actual JSON here. This seems like serialised to NSDictionary.

Comment: Just added the raw JSON..

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5. i used this example to parse json datas.simple and helpful one

Comment: @vishnuvarthan Great reference! This tutorial is wonderful! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply changed my objectForKey to valueForKey, and it worked!! It makes perfect sense there are literally no objects within the categories array, only strings, or values.

Thanks for all you help guys! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
//1
#define kLatestKivaLoansURL [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/vishnup/Documents/document.json"]
//2

#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
  [super viewDidLoad];

 dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                    kLatestKivaLoansURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                           withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
//parse out the json data
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1

                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

NSArray* Details = [json objectForKey:@"catogeries"]; //2



// 1) Get the latest loan
NSDictionary* yourValues = [Details objectAtIndex:0];
```

then pass the content in yourValues to your pickerview.

Comment: NSArray * values = [yourValues allValues]; self.pickerview=values; //pickerview is your picker view name. Try this

Comment: Just tried it. It's still showing up empty. Does the fact that the array that I'm trying at access is an array of strings?..

Answer (score 0):

You can get the categories like this:

```
NSDictionary* responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];
NSArray *categories = responseDictionary[@"sites"][@"categories"];
```